# Mapping an array of objects to dictionary in typescript, id as keys

Tags: typescript, key

Given some types and data like the following,
how can I hint the types in a way that I get autocompletion for the keys, i.e. `dictionary.Germany`?

```
type Entry = {
  tld: string;
  name: string;
  population: number;
};

const data: Entry[] = [
  {tld: 'de', name: 'Germany', population: 83623528},
  {tld: 'at', name: 'Austria', population: 8975552},
  {tld: 'ch', name: 'Switzerland', population: 8616571}
];

let dictionary = Object.fromEntries(data.map(item => [item.name, item]));
```

(Now `dictionary` is of type `{ [key: string]: Entry }`, e.g. `{ Germany: {tld: 'de', …}, …}`.)

---

To be clear, my objectives are:

1. The end result is to have the data in both a list of Entry objects…
2. …and an object map with the Entry objects.
3. I need to write the name of an object only once, either as `name` or key.
4. The dictionary needs to know its keys in an IDE like WebStorm.
5. `dictionary.Germany === data[0]`

Comment: By annotating `data` as `Entry[]` you have thrown out any information about `name` that it might have known.  Also `Object.entries()` is not strongly typed enough in TS to give you the key/value relationship you want, although you can merge in a custom definition. If you do that and massage the types sufficiently you get [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/W4JAaN). Is that what you're looking for? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz, nice stuff! I had to add `(Object as ObjectConstructor)` to make it work in the Jetbrains IDE, but otherwise I could apply that to my [own problem](https://tsplay.dev/wjlO1m). Also I had to upgade typscript from `5.2` to `5.3`, to make `satisfies` work in this scenario.

Comment: You almost certainly don't need `Object as ObjectConstructor`. Perhaps you needed to wrap the `ObjectConstructor` merge with `declare global { `+`}` because your code is in a module?

Comment: @jcalz It is indeed in an imported file. Is it good practice to declare that globally from inside an imported file? And as I'm already asking, what if I'm writing a library?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html has all the docs, I'm not sure what to say about best practices here. If you don't want to write a separate file in global scope, you can use `declare global` inside the module to merge. Merging isn't the only solution either, you could just use a type assertion for your single use of `Object.fromEntries()` or wrap it in your own custom function.  A library might not want to introduce new global typings.  I'm not really an expert in library authorship though so I can't be certain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of problems preventing your code from working as-is.

---

First, you [annotated](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) the type of `data` as `Entry[]`, thereby telling the compiler to throw away any more specific information about the initializing array literal. `Entry` only knows that `name` is `string`.  But you care about the string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the `name` properties.

Instead of annotating, you should probably use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to tell the compiler that you want it to keep track of all the literal types of the initializer (this is overkill if all you care about is `name` but it doesn't necessarily hurt anything).  Then, if you want to be sure that it matches `Entry[]`, you can use [the `satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator):

```
const data = [
  { tld: 'de', name: 'Germany', population: 83623528 },
  { tld: 'at', name: 'Austria', population: 8975552 },
  { tld: 'ch', name: 'Switzerland', population: 8616571 }
] as const satisfies Entry[];
```

(The above compiles only with TypeScript 5.3 or above due to [microsoft/TypeScript#55229](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/55229); in TypeScript 4.9 to 5.2 you'd need to use `readonly Entry[]` instead.)

---

Now TS knows about `"Germany"`, `"Austria"`, and `"Switzerland"`, but it doesn't have any idea that [the `Object.fromEntries()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) produces a value with those keys. The current [type definition](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/821b1d8fdfe5212563f18dd90c9b4d846f716432/src/lib/es2019.object.d.ts#L8) looks like

```
interface ObjectConstructor {
  fromEntries<T = any>(e: Iterable<readonly [PropertyKey, T]>): { [k: string]: T; };
}
```

meaning that its output always has a `string` [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures).  It's not impossible to write a more specific call signature, as was suggested in [microsoft/TypeScript#35745](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35745), but it's tricky to get it right and wasn't seen as worth the complexity.

If you want to write such a signature yourself you can do so in your own code base and [merge it in](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) like this:

```
// declare global {
interface ObjectConstructor {
  fromEntries<E extends readonly [PropertyKey, any][]>(
    entries: E
  ): { [T in E[number] as T[0]]: T[1] };
}
// }
```

That iterates over the elements of `entries` and uses [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to produce an object type.

---

After this you're pretty much done.  Still, the resulting type of `dictionary` will have this awful [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of `const`-asserted junk as its property value type, when all you really want is `Entry`.  So we can use `item satifies Entry as Entry` to safely widen `item` to `Entry` (writing `item satisfies Entry` would check it but not widen it, and writing `item as Entry` would widen it but not check it).

So, finally, that gives us:

```
let dictionary =
  Object.fromEntries(data.map(item => [item.name, item satisfies Entry as Entry]));
/* let dictionary: {
    Germany: Entry;
    Austria: Entry;
    Switzerland: Entry;
} */
```

Now you have exactly the behavior you wanted, more or less.  Is it worth it?  I suppose that depends on your use cases.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/C4TwDgpgBAogdsATiKBeKBvAUFKwA2AJgFxQDOSAlnAOYDcOUcAhgLYSkWLX2NgD2YAK75mwSvzik4Q1gCMIiBgF8GWAMaSKUQmOZooAbUYY8RUgHJCECwBombDlAsBxRa2ZwQdqAOGjxSVIADgBmADYAJlCAVkjgqGVbEzMSZzEfFnZLAEEhLkpmHz8RMQkpKGCATgB2GPrIxOTcUwI0i3UAC0zHSwBlAHdKYAAvRVE4QmLBUsCK4PCARnCYmsXErABdKGYyKE04bTIysgAzSgg9+CQQQ021amBFU+Z1aAB5OQArCHVgAGEtEghH9+IhMIxToh+KxrtxLgAeGBQCAADyekz2iAgzEIknwKEMAAVoZBEKAANIQED2TwgTZ3AB8AAoIAh4WRSDAAJSkUyGAAqUGosEMMnkik2uygAsMAAZNptSLLFttVFhlFgsPgIMAdJQ-uVmMg0IxPj8-gA6KEwuEXMjM3TAZiWjxgZnDCCsNCMoye1iWrIQez+8gnc6XWDslDSuH07nchgAegAVFAdXrCAa5saQHzGLg3IgPF4udGGLhcHkCswyzcK5XBsMxogJmk4yooCmk0A)